# Writing to HTTP Header using AJAX in MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

So basically I've written a controller with the help of some of the guys on here to submit some basic authorization into my HTTP request to the server. This is basically to encode the username and password to a specific URL on the API.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "vebra/",
        type: "POST",
    })
});
```

Above is my ajax request which is launched in the header calling the vebra controller to run.
I'm still very new to C# & ASP and not sure if my type on the jquery is correct.

Below is my controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Caching;
using System.Text;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace com.tortoise.Controllers
{
    public class VebraController : Controller
    {

        //
        // GET: /vebra/
        string username = "foo";
        string password = "foo";

        string url = "http://mywebservice.com";

        public VebraController ()
        {

            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

            string usernamePassword = (username + ":" + password);

            CredentialCache cache = new CredentialCache();

            cache.Add(new Uri(url), "Basic", new NetworkCredential (username,password));

            request.Credentials = cache;

            request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + System.Convert.ToBase64String(new ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes(usernamePassword)));

            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            // Get the token from the response: 
            string token = response.GetResponseHeader("Token");


        }
    }
}
```

The idea being that on the "request.Headers.Add" line it should be parsing the credentials created above and placing it in the http header request to the server in order to pass the basic authorization and return a "token" value which authorizes the access of the xml for 1 hour.

However when I run this it shows no signs of being placed in the http header request based on what Fiddler tells me.

It could easily be something I've missed here, but any pointers would be greatly helpful.

Comment: Assuming you're referring to the Basic Auth header request to the service, I can't reproduce. Copied your code (except for the `CredentialCache` stuff (unsure what its for), and the BASIC AUTH header, `Authorization: Basic Zm9vOmZvbw==` is sent properly (I used http://requestb.in/ instead of Fiddler). Hth...

Comment: @EdSF The auth stuff seems to be generated and everything properly, that I agree with. However the problem I have is that the Authorization: Basic isn't being put into the HTTP header going to the server. I can't work out why...

Comment: I'm saying that in my test, copying your code (with or without the `CredentialCache` parts), it **is** (being written and sent). See [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/UKrfX.png)

Comment: @EdSF I'm guessing that requestb.in does a direct HTTP header request though. My problem is that this code is within a controller and I'm trying to have this code/controller executed within the HTTP header request to the server. That's where my problem is I think.

Comment: Not exactly, I'm running your code in a controller and POSTing to Requestbin. All Requestbin does is show you what you sent to it (to debug, etc.)

Comment: MVC handles authentication for you and stores (by default) a token in an encrypted cookie.  The cookie name is .ASPXAUTH.  You can change the cookie name in web.config.  You can write your own custom authentication but you still store the token in a cookie.  I don't know what you're attempting to do here but if you just want to know the username use User.Identity.Name.  If your doing forms authentication the pass the username/password as data in your ajax command.  Then in your controller action use FormsAuthentication to create and save a token to .ASPXAUTH.

Comment: @ScottMacMaster - IINM, OP, needs to write Basic Auth headers to properly authenticate to some web service in order to obtain some expected response/token...I can't reproduce the issue with the code posted above (headers are in fact written and sent as the debug provided by Requestbin shows).

Comment: @ScottMacMaster, I don't need to know the usernam or password as i'm declaring those within the controller. The controller runs fine and creates the basic authentication etc. My problem seems to be that it doesn't place it into the header in order for it to return a "token" which is written into the encrypted cookie.

The token is an API generated token by the web service to access its produced XML stored behind the authentication.